# Spam protection for headless webforms

Tags: webforms, 10

I'm investigating headless Drupal for a new (Drupal 10) site and trying to understand how to protect the webforms from spam. I'm planning to use the [Webform REST](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_rest) module to help build/submit the forms.

I can see plenty of modules which offer spam protection for webforms (Honeypot, various Recaptcha options), but none of them mention how (or if) they work with a headless site.

The closest I've found is the last comment in [this issue](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_rest/issues/3259841), which suggests a combination of Gatsby, Simple Recaptcha, and various custom bits of code.

What do other people out there use?